# При создании карты по требованию относительные размеры не работают

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

При создании карты путем задания размеров 100vw и 100vh используя базовый пример
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/mapbasics
Карта создается на весь экран без проблем.

НО
При попытке создания карта по требованию (нажатии на кнопку) из следующего примера
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/request_map
с размерами 100vw и 100vh карта не создается, только с фиксированными размерами типа
style="width: 450px; height: 320px"

Для чего мне это нужно. Я хочу на телефоне при нажатии кнопки открывалась карта на весь экран телефона, потому что маленькая карта на телефоне это не комильфо. Там у меня должен быть выбор точки назначения для доставки и расчет стоимости согласно примера
https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsbox/2.1/deliveryCalculator

Comment: А зачем менять размер блока карты, если у неё есть фуллскрин-режим и кнопка для него в контролах стандартных - control.FullscreenControl ?

Comment: Большинство пользователей не знают как пользоваться картой.ю Нужно чтобы интерфейс был максимально прост. Сразу все было развернуто на весь экран. Еще попробуй попади в кнопку на телефоне, когда карта занимает половину экран.  Есть еще нюансы с картой для решения которых не нужно захламлять карту кнопками

Comment: А кто вас ограничивает кнопкой карты? У карты есть отдельный метод map.enterFullscreen(), чтобы вызывать его самостоятельно. Повесьте его на свою кастомную кнопку и всё: https://yandex.ru/dev/maps/jsapi/doc/2.1/ref/reference/map.Container.html#method_detail__enterFullscreen

Comment: У меня вообще бы вопросов не было, если бы работало. Попробовал реализовать через этот метод и получил в ответ ошибку: Uncaught TypeError: myMap.enterFullscreen is not a function. Версия 2.1

Comment: Это метод для контейнера, не для самой карты: myMap.container.enterFullscreen(); Прошу прощения, что не совсем верно применение описал, но метод верный и рабочий.